# How do I find then update values in maps in a series of vectors in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

What would be an elegant way to find the `ba4` values for `:foo` in a data structure like:

`[[{:foo "ba1"}{:foo "ba2"}] [{:foo "ba3"}{:foo "ba4"}]]`

and add the `:bif "baf"` key and value so the map(s) containing the key/value I sought so I had:

`[[{:foo "ba1"}{:foo "ba2"}] [{:foo "ba3"}{:foo "ba4" :bif "baf"}]]`?

This is the main thing I am trying to figure out; I do wonder about how you would do this if there were multiple levels of nested maps, but that will be next for me to understand.

I have, I think, seen various libraries out there for tackling this sort of thing and I'm not at all against using them, though they would have to work in ClojureScript.

I am trying to update a Reagent atom such that classes will change on a UI element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I learned a bit about [decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and [`merge`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/merge) from [Rulle's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66915198/2596132).)

What you're describing is [walking](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk) a nested data structure. Postwalking or prewalking take [every possible subform](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk) of your nested data structure and applies a function against it.

Here's how I got your desired solution using [`postwalk`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk) (note: [`assoc`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc) adds a key-value to a map):

```
(ns walking.core
  (:require [clojure.walk :as w]))

(clojure.walk/postwalk #(if (and (map? %) (= (:foo %) "ba4")) (assoc % :bif "baf") %) 
  [[{:foo "ba1"} {:foo "ba2"}] [{:foo "ba3"} {:foo "ba4"}]])
;;=> [[{:foo "ba1"} {:foo "ba2"}] [{:foo "ba3"} {:foo "ba4", :bif "baf"}]]
```

And it works no matter how nested it gets:

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk #(if (and (map? %) (= (:foo %) "ba4")) (assoc % :bif "baf") %) 
  [[{:foo "ba1"} {:foo "ba2"}] [[{:foo "ba3"} {:test {:foo "ba4"}}]]])
;;=> [[{:foo "ba1"} {:foo "ba2"}] [[{:foo "ba3"} {:test {:foo "ba4", :bif "baf"}}]]]
```

Why `postwalk` instead of `prewalk`? Both work.

```
(clojure.walk/prewalk #(if (and (map? %) (= (:foo %) "ba4")) (assoc % :bif "baf") %) 
  [[{:foo "ba1"} {:foo "ba2"}] [{:foo "ba3"} {:foo "ba4"}]])
;;=> [[{:foo "ba1"} {:foo "ba2"}] [{:foo "ba3"} {:foo "ba4", :bif "baf"}]]
```

You don't have to `lein install` anything, and it's part of Clojure; you just have to require it.

Comment: This is awesome, too! I like not having to add dependencies in both your solutions (yours and Rulle's). I'm always interested in libraries, too, but I should always reach for stock Clojure when I can.

Comment: By the way, super like how this works with nested maps!

Answer (score 2):

Clojure is quite convenient for defining mini-languages for these sorts of things. A general and fairly reusable solution does not have to be much longer than a specialized one. Here is one suggestion if you are not interested in using a library.

Essentially, you want a function to update a datastructure. This function could be expressed using elementary functions of the same kind that serve as building blocks, making up a mini-language that I referred to before. In this example, the building blocks will be `vector-scanner` and `map-decorator`. We combine these functions into `my-path` that will perform the full update.

```
;; Path building blocks
(defn vector-scanner [subpath]
  #(mapv subpath %))

(defn map-decorator [k v decoration]
  #(if (and (map? %) (= v (k %)))
     (merge % decoration)
     %))

;; Function to do the update
(def my-path (-> (map-decorator :foo "ba4" {:bif "baf"})
                 vector-scanner
                 vector-scanner))

;; Running it
(my-path [[{:foo "ba1"}{:foo "ba2"}] [{:foo "ba3"}{:foo "ba4"}]])
;; => [[{:foo "ba1"} {:foo "ba2"}] [{:foo "ba3"} {:foo "ba4", :bif "baf"}]]
```

This approach is quite similar in spirit to how [transducers](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) can be combined in various configurations.

Comment: Just learned [what decorators are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). Calling it a decorator's a good way of putting it.

Comment: Thank you for this! It's great to see the 'decorator' pattern in use, as Aaron mentioned. It's so cool how Clojure can implement everything one has already learned.

Comment: Side note: I never really know what to do with the 'Accepted Answer' thing that one should click. Not clicking it makes me feel like I'm not appreciative. On the other hand, choosing an answer seems weird when every answer is a different approach. I wish they didn't have this feature. I always wonder if not choosing someone's answer makes them less likely to answer. That's not as likely probably in the functional programming scene. I'll just click on Aaron's  as theirs works recursively, but yours is totally equally valuable to me. Please keep answering! :-)